# What would be a smart data structure to use to represent pieces of a dissection puzzle?

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, puzzle

I should keep some pieces of a dissection puzzle and search it to find solution for it.
Search and informed search. I should find a good heuristic.

What would be a smart data structure to use to represent pieces of this dissection puzzle? My dissection puzzle is something like these pictures: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/junkyard/2-6-9-11.gif

Comment: I can't think of anything better than a small bitmap, i.e. a two-dimensional array of bool which indicates the used spaces.

Comment: Hmm... I thought about it ... but I have many pieces with different sizes and they are also irregular like this picture . and I should think to rotation too... So could help me this solution?

Answer (score 0):

With an influence from graphics and how objects are represented when using OpenGL, I would create a set of all line segments (edge), each with a list of its (x,y) endpoints called (vertex) and a unique indicator for that edge :

```
edge    followed by its (x,y)  vertices
____    ____________________________________
0       (2,3)  (3,7)  
1       (3,9)  (11,9)
2       (22,9)  (22,7)
...      ....
```

then separately, for each irregular shape of the puzzle, define a list of edges which defines its boundary

```
shape    list of edges which define its boundary
____     _________________________________________
0        3,  1,   5,  8
1        7,  2,  4,  10,  4,  20
```

So in above example, shape number 0 (puzzle piece) is defined by four edges :  3,1,5,8 and so would be a four sided object (each side is always an edge)

The edge 1 is defined by the (x,y) endpoints at either end of its line segment (all edges only have two endpoints)  in the example their x&y values are  (2,3) and  (3,7)

To keep our sanity, a puzzle object is a list of edges defined by walking around the puzzle piece perimeter in a counter-clockwise direction (or clockwise as long as your are consistent)